# Pandas create percentile field based on groupby with level 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index, percentile

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    ('Group', 'group'): ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
    ('sum', 'sum'): [234, 234,544,7,332,766]
    })
```

I'd like to create a new field which calculates the percentile of each value of "sum" per group in "group". The trouble is, I have 2 header columns and cannot figure out how to avoid getting the error:

```
ValueError: level > 0 only valid with MultiIndex
```

when I run this:

```
df=df.groupby('Group',level=1).sum.rank(pct=True, ascending=False)
```

I need to keep the headers in the same structure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group by the first column, `('Group', 'group')`, and compute the rank for the `('sum', 'sum')` column use:

```
In [106]: df['rank'] = (df[('sum', 'sum')].groupby(df[('Group', 'group')]).rank(pct=True, ascending=False))

In [107]: df
Out[107]: 
  Group  sum      rank
  group  sum          
0     a  234  0.833333
1     a  234  0.833333
2     a  544  0.333333
3     b    7  1.000000
4     b  332  0.666667
5     b  766  0.333333
```

Note that `.rank(pct=True)` computes a *percentage* rank, not a *percentile*. To compute a percentile you could use [`scipy.stats.percentileofscore`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.percentileofscore.html).

```
import scipy.stats as stats
df['percentile'] = (df[('sum', 'sum')].groupby(df[('Group', 'group')])
    .apply(lambda ser: 100-pd.Series([stats.percentileofscore(ser, x, kind='rank') 
           for x in ser], index=ser.index)))
```

yields

```
  Group  sum      rank percentile
  group  sum                     
0     a  234  0.833333  50.000000
1     a  234  0.833333  50.000000
2     a  544  0.333333   0.000000
3     b    7  1.000000  66.666667
4     b  332  0.666667  33.333333
5     b  766  0.333333   0.000000
```